# django form validation looks like bad code

Tags: django, validation, styles

I've done my first validator for a form, and I have a feeling this is not the way it is supposed to be done.

It works, but it looks like ugly code, can someone help out here?

my form:

```
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to create or edit Countries."""

    class Meta:
        model = Country

    def clean_name(self):
        raw_data = self.cleaned_data['name']
        data = raw_data.title()

        try:
            Province.objects.get(name=data).exists()
            raise forms.ValidationError("There is already a province with the name: %s") % data
        except:
            pass
        try:
            Region.objects.get(name=data).exists()
            raise forms.ValidationError("There is already a region with the name: %s") % data
        except:
            pass
    return data
```

my idea is to see if the name exists as name in two other models and raise a error when it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong Queryset method here. `get()` returns a model object, which doesn't in turn have an `exists()` method. You should use `filter()`.

Also, `exists()` doesn't raise an exception. So you can just do a normal `if`:

```
if Province.objects.filter(name=data).exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError(...)
```

Bear in mind as well that the `clean` method will be called for an update as well as a create. On an update, the check will fail because it will find the very same instance you're editing. You should bypass this check if the form has an instance and the instance has a `pk` value:

```
if not (form.instance and form.instance.pk):
```

Finally, you should *never* use a bare `except` statement. That will catch all exceptions, potentially hiding some real problems with your code. Always catch the specific exception you think your code will raise - in this case, `Province.DoesNotExist`.

Comment: However i am a bit unsure, where to place if not (form.instance and form.instance.pk):  I thought before the 2 other check with them indented, but that doesnt seem to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since you'll always handle the exception in your `clean_name` function and never raise the validation exception!

Instead do this

```
if Province.objects.filter(name=data).exists() or Region.objects.filter(name=date).exists():
  raise forms.ValidationError("...")
```

Beyond that, your code is just fine !

Comment: `Province.objects.get(name=data)` throws an exception if record not found, or mulitple records are returned.

Comment: Yes, you need to use filter instead of get.